# Azure Redis Cache: Reading is not allowed after reader was completed

Tags: c#, azure, redis, background, backgroundworker

I wrote cache-update functionality.

Here is my Redis Cache implementation:

```
    public class RedisCache : ICache
    {
        private readonly IDatabase _cache;

        public RedisCache(string connectionString)
        {
            var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
            _cache = connection.GetDatabase();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
        {
            var value = await _cache.StringGetAsync(key);

            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
            }

            return default(T);
        }

        public async Task SetAsync<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan ttl)
        {
            var serializedValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

            await _cache.StringSetAsync(key, serializedValue, ttl);
        }

        public T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            var value = _cache.StringGet(key);

            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
            }

            return default(T);
        }

        public void Set<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan ttl)
        {
            var serializedValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

            _cache.StringSet(key, serializedValue, ttl);
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
        {
            await _cache.KeyDeleteAsync(key);
        }
    }
```

And usage in `BackgroundService`:

```
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            _cache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ICache>();
            _queue = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RefresBackgroundQueue>();
            
            await foreach (string item in _queue.DequeueAllAsync(stoppingToken))
            {
                try
                {
                    // some logic
                    await _cache.GetAsync<Model>(key)
                    // some logic
                    await _cache.SetAsync(randomKey, result, new TimeSpan(100, 0, 0, 0));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Exception while updating cache: {ex.Message}, {ex.StackTrace}");
                }
            }
        }
```

From code above i am getting uncatchable exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Reading is not allowed after reader was completed.
> at System.IO.Pipelines.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_NoReadingAllowed()
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.AdvanceReader(SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.AdvanceTo(SequencePosition consumed, SequencePosition examined)
> at StackExchange.Redis.PhysicalConnection.ReadFromPipe() in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/PhysicalConnection.cs:line 1729

What should i do in that situation?

Answer (score 1):

I made few changes in **ExecuteAsync** in **BackgroundService.cs**,
Code is working fine

Changes in **ExecuteAsync**
[image]

**Full Code**

```
  using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
  using System;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbLoggerCategory;
    
    public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService> _logger;
    
        public MyBackgroundService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<MyBackgroundService> logger)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _logger = logger;
        }
    
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("MyBackgroundService is starting.");
    
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Your background service logic here
    
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken); // Simulate some work
            }
    
            _logger.LogInformation("MyBackgroundService is stopping.");
    
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var cache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICache>();
            var queue = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RefreshBackgroundQueue>();
    
            await foreach (string item in queue.DequeueAllAsync(stoppingToken))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Your logic here
                    var key = item; 
    
                    // Retrieve data from cache
                    var model = await cache.GetAsync<Model>(key);
    
                    // Perform some processing
                    var processedResult = ProcessModel(model);
    
                    // Store result in cache
                    var randomKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    
                    await cache.SetAsync(randomKey, processedResult, TimeSpan.FromDays(1)); // Adjust the TTL as needed
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Exception while updating cache: {ex.Message}, {ex.StackTrace}");
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

**In code i have used below conditions**

1. `while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)`
   This is the main loop of your background service. It continues to execute as long as the cancellation token (`stoppingToken`) has not been signaled for cancellation. The cancellation token is typically used to gracefully stop background operations when the application is shutting down.
2. `await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);`
   Inside the loop, this line of code introduces a delay of 1000 milliseconds (1 second) between iterations of the loop. The `await` keyword indicates that this operation is asynchronous and allows other tasks to execute concurrently while the delay is occurring.